# How to use a session in a login script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I have three files

- index.php
- login.php
- auth.php

My login form is based on my index.php. i including the login.php on the index page.

i want it so when i log in, it will be authenticated by auth.php (which is does) and a message will be displayed on auth.php which says "Your login was successfully" (which is does), however, when it goes back to the index page it comes up with the login form instead of saying "Welcome USER you have successfully logged in.

I believe the error comes from the session mainly because i do not know what else could be wrong.

Here is my code of each page.

Index.php:

```
<?php include ("login.php"); ?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
if ($loggedin){
    echo '<h2>Logged in</h2><p style="font-size:14px;">Welcome '.$user.' you have sucessfully logged in.</p>';
}
else {
     echo '
       <h2>Login</h2>
       <form action="auth.php" method="POST">
       <div class="smallform">
                <p><span>Username:</span><br>
                <input type="text" name="user"></p>
                <p><span>Password:</span><br>
                <input type="password" name="pass"></p>
                <p style="padding-top: 15px"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        </div>
        </form>';
}
?>
```

Auth.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("HoST", "USER", "PASS", "DBNAME");
$user = $_POST["user"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$sql = "SELECT UserID FROM Customer 
        WHERE UserID = \"$user\"
        AND Password = md5(\"$pass\")";

$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
<title>VeloCity</title>
<link href="_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=index.php" />'; ?>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
<?php 
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)==1){
    $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
    echo "You have sucessfully logged in";
}
else{
    echo "You have entered an incorrect password. Please try again";
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Where is $loggedin declared?

Comment: And where declared `$name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sessions it's best to put session_start(); right at the very top of the page. Line 1 as this avoids session setting errors.

On every page you make that you want restricted access to you will need to apply session_start(); on every page.

There after you can add your custom session rules. So after the database check you'd need to create a session variable within the Auth.php file like so:

```
$_SESSION['loggedin']['username']=$_POST['users'];
$_SESSION['loggedin']['bros'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); // To secure not needed in some cases.
```

Then for every other page you want to check that the session exists.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
    //view page = true
}
```

EDIT :
better validation;

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin']['bros'] !== md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    die('No access');
    sleep(1);
    header('location:Auth.php');
}
```

apply that to the top of the index page and remove the include(Auth.php); that should work better.

Comment: No problem inbox me if you have any other problems

Comment: I am trying to logout i am doing session_destory(); but it is not working for some reason can you help me in anyway?

Comment: Where are you putting session_destroy(); ?

Comment: I made a new file called logout.php and added session_start();
session_destroy();

Comment: Nope, to my knowledge session_destroy should end the session but for some reason it keeps me logged in maybe i have to delete a cookie or something.

Comment: there are no cookies. It will be with the ifStatment to view the page. I'll edit my post with a better validation.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mohammed and welcome.

You are almost there, you set

```
$_SESSION["user"] = $user;
```

and you validate

```
if ($loggedin){
  echo '<h2>Logged in</h2>...'
}
```

You should probably be doing something like

```
if(isset($_SESSION["user"]) && !empty($_SESSION["user"])) { 
  echo '<h2>Logged in</h2>...' \
}
```

You were checking a variable that had not been set, so by default was false.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer but again it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something you don't set $loggedin anywhere.

Change the following parts, in the login.php

```
if ($_SESSION["loggedin"]){
    echo '<h2>Logged in</h2><p style="font-size:14px;">Welcome '.$_SESSION["user"].' you have sucessfully logged in.</p>';
}
```

...and then in Auth.php ...

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)==1){
    $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
    $_SESSION["loggedin"] = True;
    echo "You have sucessfully logged in";
}
```

Although you could just check for a value in $_SESSION["user"] rather than store a loggedin flag.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your quick reply. However, it doesn't seem to work. You said change both parts in the login.php but the second part is in the auth.php

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add "...and then in Auth.php...", both are just small edits to the existing code.